# Expresso Store, modifiers and price value for first modifier

Tags: expresso-store, price-modifier

I'm trying to retrieve price value for first modifier (*only*) within **entries** tag. My code looks like

`{if product_details:price_val!=0}
    {product_details:price_val}
 {if:else}
 {product_details:modifiers}
     {product_details:price_mod_val}
  {/product_details:modifiers}
 {/if}`

but always it returns an empty value for first modifier.

Any clue hot to bite that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on directions from Ian (thanks!) I have finally got solution to my question.

To obtain first price (or all) for product modifiers I have used code below:

```
<?php $prices = array(); ?>
 {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" disable_form="yes" disable_javascript="yes"}
    {modifiers}
        {modifier_options}
            {if price_mod_val}<?php $prices[] = {price_mod_val}; ?> {/if}
        {/modifier_options}
    {/modifiers}
 {/exp:store:product}
```

and then Pinterest OpenGraph part:

```
<?php if(!empty($prices)) {?>
<meta property="og:price:amount" content="<?php $price = number_format($prices[0], 2, '.', ''); echo $price; ?>" />    
<?php }
else { ?>
<meta property="og:price:amount" content="{if product_details:price_val!=0}{product_details:price_val}{if:else}99.99{/if}" />
<?php } ?>
```

I have try to use jQuery `change` to replace selected option price, but this works only when a visitor pin from that particular selection, but doesn't work when Pinterest will crawl back for price change/update. At that point I have stick only to primary (landing) product option.

UPDATE:

Stash version:

```
 {exp:stash:set_list name="price_list" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="3" parse_conditionals="yes"}
 {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" disable_form="yes" disable_javascript="yes"}
    {modifiers}
        {modifier_options}
            {if price_mod_val}{stash:item_price}{price_mod_val}{/stash:item_price}{/if}
        {/modifier_options}
    {/modifiers}
 {/exp:store:product}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

and OpenGrap price for Stash version:

```
{if {exp:stash:not_empty name="price_list"}}
{exp:stash:get_list name="price_list" limit="1" parse_tags="yes" parse_conditionals="yes"}
<meta property="og:price:amount" content="{item_price}" />    
{/exp:stash:get_list}
{if:else}
<meta property="og:price:amount" content="{product_details:price_val}" />
{/if}
```

Comment: You got it. Although if you (or anyone else) wanted to do the same thing without enabling PHP in their templates then Stash is a good option to store and re-use a variable elsewhere in the template or in the session.

Comment: Totally forgot about Stash (I have used it across my site). Will check it and post update.

Answer (score 0):

To pull out the price for a modifier you should just need to do something like this:

```
{modifiers}
    {modifier_options}
        {if price_mod_val} ({price_mod}) {/if}
    {/modifier_options}
{/modifiers}
```

This will usually be done inside a select box for allowing a selection of each modifier option but above I've just stripped out all the HTML to place emphases on the Store tags only.

`{price_mod}` is the one which displays the price and `{if price_mod_val}` checks if it has a price to show

Comment: This is not working within `entries` loop tag (I have mentioned that in OP) and I need to retrieve only first `price_mod_val`. Your example is good when you do all modifiers selectors within `store` loop tag.

Comment: You wont be able to access modifier values without using Store tags but Store tags can sit within you EE channel entries loop. Use the `{modifiers}` tag pair if using the Product tag or `{items}` tag pair if using Checkout or Order tags.

Comment: Well, my goal is to get price passed to OpenGraph for Pinterest. As OpenGraph works only with 1 product option it requires to get that from first `price_mod_val`

Comment: No problem in using `price_mod_val` but you just need to wrap it in Store tags. If you need it elsewhere just save it as a session variable and call it out when and where needed.